# Drupal 8 - Problem with composer dependencies

Tags: drupal, composer-php, drupal-8

I'm having trouble updating my Drupal 8 core version.
Composer says I shouldn't install drupal/core-renderer 8.2.0 and remove the Drupal core.

I tried removing the composer.lock file, the vendor folder and replacing the core version to v8.2.0 as requested by composer but when I run "composer require drupal/core" it always installs version ^8.7 (latest).
Clearing the composer cache didn't help either.

I also don't understand the problem with the psr-http-message-bridge. It doesn't appear on my composer.json file, it's something internal to the Drupal core.

This is the composer command output:

```
Problem 1
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.2.0|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.2.0-beta1|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.2.0-beta2|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.2.0-beta3|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.2.0-rc1|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.2.0-rc2|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.2.1|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.2.2|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.2.3|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.2.4|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.2.5|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.2.6|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.2.7|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.2.8|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.2.x-dev|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.3.0|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.3.0-alpha1|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.3.0-beta1|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.3.0-rc1|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.3.0-rc2|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.3.1|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.3.2|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.3.3|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.3.4|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.3.5|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.3.6|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.3.7|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.3.8|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.3.9|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.3.x-dev|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.4.0|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.4.0-alpha1|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.4.0-beta1|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.4.0-rc1|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.4.0-rc2|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.4.1|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.4.2|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.4.3|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.4.4|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.4.5|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.4.6|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.4.7|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.4.8|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.4.x-dev|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.5.0|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.5.0-alpha1|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.5.0-beta1|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.5.0-rc1|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.5.1|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.5.10|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.5.11|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.5.12|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.5.13|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.5.14|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.5.15|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.5.2|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.5.3|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.5.4|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.5.5|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.5.6|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.5.7|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.5.8|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.5.9|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.5.x-dev|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.6.0|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.6.0-alpha1|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.6.0-beta1|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.6.0-beta2|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.6.0-rc1|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.6.1|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.6.10|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.6.11|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.6.12|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.6.13|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.6.14|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.6.15|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.6.16|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.6.17|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.6.2|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.6.3|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.6.4|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.6.5|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.6.6|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.6.7|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.6.8|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.6.9|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.6.x-dev|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.7.0|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.7.0-alpha1|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.7.0-alpha2|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.7.0-beta1|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.7.0-beta2|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.7.0-rc1|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.7.1|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.7.2|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.7.3|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.7.4|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.7.5|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.7.6|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.7.7|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.7.8|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.7.x-dev|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core-render 8.8.x-dev|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer|remove drupal/core 8.7.8
    - don't install drupal/core 8.7.0|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core 8.7.0-alpha1|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core 8.7.0-alpha2|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core 8.7.0-beta1|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core 8.7.0-beta2|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core 8.7.0-rc1|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core 8.7.1|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core 8.7.2|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core 8.7.3|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core 8.7.4|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core 8.7.5|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core 8.7.6|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core 8.7.7|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core 8.7.8|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core 8.7.x-dev|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core 8.8.x-dev|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core 8.3.x-dev|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core 8.4.x-dev|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core 8.5.x-dev|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - don't install drupal/core 8.6.x-dev|remove drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer
    - drupal/core 8.2.x-dev requires symfony/psr-http-message-bridge v0.2 -> satisfiable by symfony/psr-http-message-bridge[v0.2] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - Installation request for drupal/drupal dev-prueba_composer -> satisfiable by drupal/drupal[dev-prueba_composer].
    - Installation request for drupal/core-render ^8.2 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.2.x-dev, 8.3.x-dev, 8.4.x-dev, 8.5.x-dev, 8.6.x-dev, 8.7.0, 8.7.0-alpha1, 8.7.0-alpha2, 8.7.0-beta1, 8.7.0-beta2, 8.7.0-rc1, 8.7.1, 8.7.2, 8.7.3, 8.7.4, 8.7.5, 8.7.6, 8.7.7, 8.7.8, 8.7.x-dev, 8.8.x-dev], drupal/core-render[8.2.0, 8.2.0-beta1, 8.2.0-beta2, 8.2.0-beta3, 8.2.0-rc1, 8.2.0-rc2, 8.2.1, 8.2.2, 8.2.3, 8.2.4, 8.2.5, 8.2.6, 8.2.7, 8.2.8, 8.2.x-dev, 8.3.0, 8.3.0-alpha1, 8.3.0-beta1, 8.3.0-rc1, 8.3.0-rc2, 8.3.1, 8.3.2, 8.3.3, 8.3.4, 8.3.5, 8.3.6, 8.3.7, 8.3.8, 8.3.9, 8.3.x-dev, 8.4.0, 8.4.0-alpha1, 8.4.0-beta1, 8.4.0-rc1, 8.4.0-rc2, 8.4.1, 8.4.2, 8.4.3, 8.4.4, 8.4.5, 8.4.6, 8.4.7, 8.4.8, 8.4.x-dev, 8.5.0, 8.5.0-alpha1, 8.5.0-beta1, 8.5.0-rc1, 8.5.1, 8.5.10, 8.5.11, 8.5.12, 8.5.13, 8.5.14, 8.5.15, 8.5.2, 8.5.3, 8.5.4, 8.5.5, 8.5.6, 8.5.7, 8.5.8, 8.5.9, 8.5.x-dev, 8.6.0, 8.6.0-alpha1, 8.6.0-beta1, 8.6.0-beta2, 8.6.0-rc1, 8.6.1, 8.6.10, 8.6.11, 8.6.12, 8.6.13, 8.6.14, 8.6.15, 8.6.16, 8.6.17, 8.6.2, 8.6.3, 8.6.4, 8.6.5, 8.6.6, 8.6.7, 8.6.8, 8.6.9, 8.6.x-dev, 8.7.0, 8.7.0-alpha1, 8.7.0-alpha2, 8.7.0-beta1, 8.7.0-beta2, 8.7.0-rc1, 8.7.1, 8.7.2, 8.7.3, 8.7.4, 8.7.5, 8.7.6, 8.7.7, 8.7.8, 8.7.x-dev, 8.8.x-dev].
```

And this is my composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "drupal/drupal",
    "description": "Drupal is an open source content management platform powering millions of websites and applications.",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "require": {
        "drupal/core": "^8.7",
        "composer/installers": "^1.0.24",
        "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "^1.4",
        "drush/drush": "^9.0",
        "symfony/property-access": "^3.2.",
        "gufy/pdftohtml-php":"~2",
        "mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf": "~2.0",
        "tecnickcom/tcpdf": "6.0.*",
        "dompdf/dompdf" : "0.6.*",
        "mpdf/mpdf" : "5.7.*",
        "wa72/htmlpagedom": "1.3.*",
        "smalot/pdfparser": "*",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.4.*"
    },
    "replace": {
        "drupal/metatag": "8.*",
        "drupal/slick": "8.*",
        "drupal/superfish": "8.*",
        "drupal/swiftmailer": "8.*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "autoloader-suffix": "Drupal8"
    },
    "extra": {
        "_readme": [
            "By default Drupal loads the autoloader from ./vendor/autoload.php.",
            "To change the autoloader you can edit ./autoload.php.",
            "This file specifies the packages.drupal.org repository.",
            "You can read more about this composer repository at:",
            "https://www.drupal.org/node/2718229"
        ],
        "merge-plugin": {
            "include": [
                "core/composer.json",
                "modules/contrib/metatag/composer.json",
                "modules/contrib/slick/composer.json",
                "modules/contrib/superfish/composer.json",
                "modules/contrib/swiftmailer/composer.json"
            ],
            "recurse": true,
            "replace": false,
            "merge-extra": false
        },
        "installer-paths": {
            "core": [
                "type:drupal-core"
            ],
            "modules/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-module"
            ],
            "profiles/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-profile"
            ],
            "themes/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-theme"
            ],
            "drush/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-drush"
            ],
            "modules/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-module"
            ],
            "themes/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-theme"
            ]
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\": "core/lib/Drupal/Core/Composer",
            "Drupal\\composer_manager\\Composer\\": "modules/contrib/composer_manager/src/Composer"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "pre-autoload-dump": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::preAutoloadDump",
        "post-autoload-dump": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::ensureHtaccess",
        "post-package-install": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup",
        "post-package-update": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup",
        "drupal-phpunit-upgrade-check": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::upgradePHPUnit",
        "drupal-phpunit-upgrade": "@composer update phpunit/phpunit --with-dependencies --no-progress",
        "phpcs": "phpcs --standard=core/phpcs.xml.dist --runtime-set installed_paths $($COMPOSER_BINARY config vendor-dir)/drupal/coder/coder_sniffer --",
        "phpcbf": "phpcbf --standard=core/phpcs.xml.dist --runtime-set installed_paths $($COMPOSER_BINARY config vendor-dir)/drupal/coder/coder_sniffer --"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
Reading endless posts I came across a supposed problem with the wikimedia merge plugin. I tried to repeat the composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies removing the merge plugin include in the root composer.json and at least it finished without problems, but I don't know if all dependencies are correctly installed or if I will need to include this again for future core updates.

Comment: The composer.lock file should never be deleted like that. It contains vital information regarding the version of modules/themes used in our project and removing it would cause to lost that information. Removing that file should never be part of any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of wikimedia merge plugin is deprecated in favor of a path repository on composer.json.
The solution to this problem was to remove the composer include of the Drupal core from the merge plugin section:

```
"merge-plugin": {
        "include": [
            "core/composer.json", <-- Remove
            "modules/contrib/metatag/composer.json",
            "modules/contrib/slick/composer.json",
            "modules/contrib/superfish/composer.json",
            "modules/contrib/swiftmailer/composer.json"
        ],
        "recurse": true,
        "replace": false,
        "merge-extra": false
    }
```